# explanation of the following text-manipulation command in vim

Tags: vim

I got to know a quite powerful vim command, but I cannot figure out its meaning. Could anyone here please give detailed explanation？

```
:g/^/,+1 m -1 | +1 d 3
```

I tried reading the help system, but found not so easy.

Comment: What does this "powerful" command do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes over all lines in the buffer (`:global` with the pattern `^` matches everywhere).

For each line, it `:move`s the line plus the next `+1` one (so two lines) above `-1`, then `:delete`s  `3` following `+1` lines.

Essentially, it takes 2 lines, then drops 3 lines, and so on, until it errors out at the end of the buffer (with `E16: Invalid range`).